# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined when I execute cucumber.js

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, cucumber

I'm implement cucumber on my framework working with protractor,

this is the tree of my framework

```
- FM_cucumber
  - features
    - steps
      * my_steps.js
    * login.feature
  - node_modules
  - test
  * conf.js
  * package.json
```

Inside of my *my_steps.js* i have this

```
var steps = function(){
  this.Given(/^Open google$/, function () {
    this.browser.get('http://www.google.com').then(function(result){
       callback(result);
      });
    });
  };
module.exports = steps;
```

So to execute this feature i'm using the command *cucumber.js* of course i'm in the folder where I have my *FM_cucumber* but after I execute the *cucumber.js* is displaying this typeError

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
     at World.<anonymous> (/Users/myname/Documents/FM_cucumber/features/steps/my_steps.js:4:19)
```

Is anybody se something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you are binding the protractor `browser`-object to the `this`(World) of CucumberJS. Protractor can 'live' on it's own in combination with CucumberJS. You *only* use CucumberJS to:

- create featurefiles
- create the binding between the featurefiles and the step implementation (with the RegEx)
- use it for Hooks / Reporting

The code within the step implementation can be *native* Protractor syntax. So for you problem, change this

```
var steps = function(){
  this.Given(/^Open google$/, function () {
    this.browser.get('http://www.google.com').then(function(result){
       callback(result);
      });
    });
  };
module.exports = steps;
```

into this

```
var steps = function(){
  this.Given(/^Open google$/, function () {
    browser.get('http://www.google.com')
      .then(function(result){
       callback(result);
      });
    });
  };
module.exports = steps;
```

Be aware of the fact that the `browser.get()` doesn't have a result, see [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.get)

Hope it helps